# Ring containing a Dedekind ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose I have two domains, $A\subset B$, where $A$ is Dedekind and $\operatorname{Frac}(A)=\operatorname{Frac}(B)$. I also know that $B$ is both integrally closed and has height $1$. Is $B$ necessarily Dedekind? If not, I'd love to see a counterexample.

(Note: I'm adding the homework tag since this is motivated by (and would finish off) a homework problem about global function fields, although I now know another way, with slightly stronger hypotheses, to get the necessary result with Riemann-Roch.)

Comment: When you say "height one", do you mean "of Krull dimension one" (every non-zero prime is maximal)?

Comment: @NilsMatthes Yes. The only remaining thing to show is the Noetherian condition.

Comment: Dear @Andrew, There are lots of instances where both $A$ and $B$ are Dedekind and $B$ is not finite over $A$. For example, $A=\mathbf{Z}$ and $B=\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: Dear @KeenanKidwell, hum... nice example! These are both integrally closed as well, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Dear @Andrew, In fact, if $B$ is finite over $A$ then it is integral over $A$, and since $B\subseteq\mathrm{Frac}(A)$, $A=B$.

Comment: If $A$ has torsion class group, then every non-trivial absolute value on $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ which is bounded on $A$ comes from a maximal ideal of $A$ in the usual way, i.e., is $\mathfrak{m}$-adic for some $\mathfrak{m}$. If there were a Dedekind domain with non-torsion class group whose fraction field admitted a non-discrete (non-trivial) non-Archimedean absolute value, bounded on $A$, then the valuation ring of this absolute value would serve as an example where $B$ is not Noetherian. I have no idea if such a thing can exist though.

Comment: @Keenan You might find of interest the following results: for a domain D: every overring of D is Noetherian iff D is 1-dimensional Noetherian; every overring of D is integrally closed iff D is a Prufer domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the multiplicative theory of ideals it is well known that the overrings of Dedekind domains are also Dedekind. See, for instance, Larsen and McCarthy, *Multiplicative Theory of Ideals*, Theorem 6.21 or these [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf), Proposition 22.2.

Comment: The overrings which satisfy some condition, I guess.

Comment: An *overring* of a domain $R$ is a ring intermediate between $R$ and its fraction field $K$. This is the only condition.

Comment: Ah! I generally see that term to mean the relation converse to *subring*.

Comment: @Mariano That definition of overring is used frequently by rings theorists studying factorization / divisibility theory and related topics, e.g. see these  [various characterizations of Prufer domains.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/119552/242)