# Characterizing Dedekind domains by ideal-theoretic identities

Tags: commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\fa}{\mathfrak{a}}\newcommand{fb}{\mathfrak{b}}\newcommand{\fp}{\mathfrak{p}}$
**Motivation:** In elementary number theory, one proves that for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, $a b=\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$. This has an obvious "categorification": for any two ideals $\fa,\fb\subset\mathbb{Z}$, one has $\fa\fb=(\fa\cap\fb)(\fa+\fb)$. One can easily see that this identity holds in any Dedekind domain $A$. (Just note that 
$$
  v_\fp(\fa\fb) = v_\fp(\fa)+v_\fp(\fb) = \min\{v_\fp(\fa),v_\fp(\fb)\} + \max\{v_\fp(\fa),v_\fp(\fb)\} = v_\fp(\fa+\fb)+v_\fp(\fa\cap\fb) = v_\fp((\fa+\fb)(\fa\cap\fb))
$$
for all prime ideals $\fp\subset A$.)

I wonder if this identity characterizes Dedekind domains. Note that this is certainly not the case if we allow $A$ to be non-noetherian. For example, if $A$ is any valuation ring, then $\fa\fb=(\fa+\fb)(\fa\cap\fb)$ for all ideals $\fa\subset A$ for essentially the same reason (just make the same computation using the valuation for $A$ instead of $v_\fp$). So, suppose we restrict to the following case:

**Question 1:** *If $A$ is a noetherian local domain such that $\fa\fb=(\fa+\fb)(\fa\cap\fb)$ for all ideals $\fa,\fb\subset A$, is $A$ a discrete valuation ring?*

Of course, a positive answer would imply that any noetherian domain whose ideals satisfy the identity is Dedekind (just localize at each prime ideal).

The next question is a long shot, but here goes:

**Question 2:** *If $A$ is a local domain such that $\fa\fb=(\fa+\fb)(\fa\cap\fb)$ for all ideals $\fa,\fb\subset A$, is $A$ a valuation ring?*

Any progress towards answering either question will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that the answer to your first question is yes. I remember reading it somewhere, and the author said "I've never found this characterization Dedekind domains to be too useful," or something like that :) It's possible I imagined this, and I haven't really thought about it, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Okay, I found it. It's near the bottom of page 13 in Keith Conrad's notes: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf One needs to assume the domain is integrally closed, at least in the non-local case. I'm not sure about this for local domains.

Comment: Very nice! It would be interesting to see a proof though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition.** Let $A$ be an integral domain. Then $A$ is Prüfer iff $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}=(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b})(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})$ for all ideals $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}\subset A$.

Let me recall that one of the equivalent characterizations of Prüfer domains is the following: $A$ is Prüfer iff $A_P$ is a valuation ring for any prime ideal $P$. This shows immediately the "only if" part of the Proposition.

For the converse, we prove that every non-zero $2$-generated ideal of $A$ is invertible. Let $\mathfrak{c}=(x,y)$. If $x=0$ or $y=0$ there is nothing to prove. Suppose $x\neq 0$, $y\neq 0$. Then $\mathfrak{a}=(x)$ and $\mathfrak{b}=(y)$ are invertible and $$\mathfrak{c}(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})\mathfrak{b}^{-1}\mathfrak{a}^{-1}=(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b})(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})\mathfrak{b}^{-1}\mathfrak{a}^{-1}=\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{b}^{-1}\mathfrak{a}^{-1}=A,$$ so $\mathfrak{c}$ is invertible.

Now the answer to your questions is obviously positive.

Comment: Very nice! I spent a while assuming that $A$ was *not* a dvr and trying to derive a contradiction. Doing things directly makes it a lot cleaner!

Comment: Just to be clear: what @YACP proves is that if $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are invertible, so is $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}$. Induction on the number of generators of $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ shows you that all finitely generated ideals are invertible. [This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prüfer_domain) says there are examples of Prufer domains with finitely generated (but not two-generated) ideals.

Comment: This is one of [almost $30$ characterizations of Prufer domains here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/119552/242)