# A characterization of Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain, and that nonzero ideals of $A$ under ideal multiplication is a free commutative monoid, then $A$ is a Dedekind domain.

By Dedekind domain we mean a Noetherian normal domain of dimension $1$, or equivalently a domain whose fractional ideals form a group, or equivalently every nonzero ideal is a product of prime ideals.

This appears in **Larsen, Max D., and Paul J. McCarthy. Multiplicative theory of ideals. Academic press, 1971.**, Exercise VI.14, and also somewhere on Zariski-Samuel as exercise.

There are several attempting ways to do this. Firstly it is likely that being a free commutative monoid will imply $I \supset J \Rightarrow I \mid J$, but recall even we know a priori the basis consisting of prime ideals, this is not so direct.

Secondly I know (from various properties of Prüfer domains) that a Noetherian domain satisfying the condition is a Dedekind domain, so one may proceed by showing every (prime) ideal is invertible, or merely finitely generated. Still I can't make it through.

Comment: Which definition of dedekind domain are you using? There are close to $100$ known (if not more), e.g. see see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119552/242).

Comment: Can you show that every ideal $I$ of the monoid is inversible (there exists $J$ such that $IJ$ is principal)

Comment: @BillDubuque OK, so you may feel better if I wrote: show that the basis must consists of prime ideals.

Comment: @reuns If I could, then I would have not post the question. Perhaps there is something I missed, but I feel hard to deduce that prime ideals are invertible and thus finitely generated, which is sufficient for the purpose. I guess one perhaps need to go through stuffs on Prufer rings and reproduce some of the proof, but I am not enthusiastic enough to do this and wish someone would give me a detailed reference (i.e., not as an exercise) or an answer.

Comment: Given $I$ take $a\in I-0$ then use the free commutative monoid property to construct $J$ such that $IJ=(a)$. It implies that  $A$ is a Dedekind domain (by one of the non-trivial equivalent definitions of Dedekind domains)

Comment: @reuns The only candidate is $((a):I)$ but why it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139919/discussion-between-fyx1123581347-and-reuns).

Comment: I overlooked that $a\in I$ doesn't mean $(a)\ge I$ on the free commutative monoid side

Comment: While it is excellent you sourced the problem, please don't link to pdf copies of books.  It is almost always a bootleg pdf and therefore unethical to distribute.  We would not like such distribution to happen on the site.  (I've replaced the link with an appropriate citation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See theorem 8 in [the paper: The Cancellation Law for Ideals in a Commutative Ring](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/cancellation-law-for-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring/AB677F938F32442ABB489937818E774B), it answers Exercise VI.14 in https://promathmedia.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/multiplicative-theory-of-ideals.pdf.